# How to set selector true on back to grid view

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, longlistselector

I  use grid view here,  and i do open an full image on click of grid view item
When i do back press to my Grid view i want my last selector position true.
please help me to find out this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to save the gridview position of the clicked element when clicked. Use SharedPreferences. You can load the status in the onResume() function.